# How to generate test report using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

How can I generate test report using ***pytest***? I searched for it but whatever I got was about coverage report.
I tried with this command:

```
py.test sanity_tests.py --cov=C:\Test\pytest --cov-report=xml
```

But as parameters represents it generates coverage report not test report.

Comment: What test report are you expecting?

Comment: @jonrsharpe test report like tests successful or unsuccessful. If unsuccessful then message which is passed in assert statements.

Comment: Do you just mean what is shown in the terminal? Why not simply `>` it to a file?

Comment: @jonrsharpe as pytest generates coverage report in defined clean way, i'm wondering is there any property of pytest which can be used to generate test report in xml format. using > it will generate a text format. XML format will be easy to parse and get results store for future use.

Comment: The XML coverage report is **not** generated by `py.test`, it's generated  by [`coverage`](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/) via the `pytest-cov` plugin. As far as I know, there isn't similar functionality built into `py.test` itself. I don't know what Allure is, but this plugin refers to XML reporting: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-allure-adaptor

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. Is there any other module or package which can be used to do so?

Comment: Please do some research, I have not had this requirement so don't know.

Comment: Do you mean a XML file with the test results? Did you try the --junitxml option?

Comment: @BrunoOliveira no. how to use it?

Comment: @BrunoOliveira I tried using `py.test sample_tests.py --junitxml=C:\path` but it's throwing error
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\path'`

Comment: @fhulprogrammer have you tried it with a directory that exists and has appropriate permissions?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes directory exists and I also gave Read/Write permission to everyone. But same error `Permission denied`

Comment: @jonrsharpe try using `--junitxml=c:\path\reports.xml`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is there any command line option to generate report in html format? I can parse XML and dump contents to html but wondering if this feature already available in pytest. I tried command `--junithtml` but it's not valid parameter.

Comment: @fhulprogrammer I don't know

Comment: @fhulprogrammer there's the [pytest-html](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-html) plugin for that. Unfortunately it seems to truncate output for test failures, which made it useless for my purposes.

Answer (score 83):

Ripped from the comments: you can use the `--junitxml` argument.

```
$ py.test sample_tests.py --junitxml=C:\path\to\out_report.xml
```

Comment: Per the comments this seemed to solve the OP's problem. Marked as Community Wiki since I just paraphrased what @BrunoOliveira wrote in the comments.

Comment: Documented [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#creating-junitxml-format-files)

Comment: Documentation link update: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/output.html#creating-junitxml-format-files

Answer (score 7):

You can use a pytest plugin '**pytest-html**' for generating html reports which can be forwarded to different teams as well

First install the plugin:

```
$ pip install pytest-html
```

Second, just run your tests with this command:

```
$ pytest --html=report.html
```

You can also make use of the hooks provided by the plugin in your code.

```
import pytest
from py.xml import html

def pytest_html_report_title(report)
   report.title = "My very own title!"
```

*Reference:* https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but you can try referring to https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html. A python library that can generate HTML output.

Answer (score -2):

```
py.test --html=Report.html
```

Here you can specify your python file as well. In this case, when there is no file specified it picks up all the files with a name like 'test_%' present in the directory where the command is run and executes them and generates a report with the name Report.html

You can also modify the name of the report accordingly.

Comment: A vanilla install of pytest did not seem to have this capability in it.